# Python dictionary comprehension example

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to learn Python dictionary comprehension, and I think it is possible to do in one line what the following functions do. I wasn't able to make the `n+1` as in the first or avoid using `range()` as in the second.

Is it possible to use a counter that automatically increments during the comprehension, as in `test1()`?

```
def test1():
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    d = {}
    n = 1
    for i in l:
        d[i] = n
        n = n + 1
    return d

def test2():
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    d = {}
    for n in range(len(l)):
        d[l[n]] = n + 1
    return d
```

Comment: Is it okay to use `range` in the `dict` comprehension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite simple using the [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> {letter: i for i,letter in enumerate(L, start=1)}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Note that, if you wanted the inverse mapping, i.e. mapping `1` to `a`, `2` to `b` etc, you could simply do:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(L, start=1))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> { x:(y+1) for (x,y) in zip(l, range(len(l))) }
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `zip()`. Is it ok to use `range()` inside a comprehension?

Comment: @stenci sure, you can use range inside comprehensions

Comment: If you don't want to use range, use @Bakuriu's enumerate solution.