# Assigning ordered scalars to keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to assign integers 1,2,..., N to keys of a dictionary. Each key is a 4 dimensional vector; so I should assign numbers 1,...,N to keys of the form (i,j,k,l). It seems a trivial job; I guess I have stayed all night and my brain does not work. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `dict((key, index) for index, key in enumerate(the_sequence_of_keys, start=1))`? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513890/python-dictionary-comprehension-example  (note: in python2.7 and python3 you can also use a dict-comprehension: `{key: index for index, key in enumerate(sequence_of_i_j_k_l, start=1)}`).

Comment: Do you want create dictionary like `{(1,2,3,4):1, (2,3,4,5):2, ....., (n,n+1,n+2,n+3):n}`?

Comment: Is there some relation between `i,j,k,l` and the value in the dictionary? Otherwise, if you simply want to "enumerate" these keys, my previous comment already solves your problem.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Actually, there is not. All I need to do is to assign a unique number to each key of a dictionary.

Comment: @NNsr Than my comment already provides a solution, since each key will have a different value. It's also easy to insert new keys with unique values, since you can keep track of the maximum inserted. If you want to use random numbers then you should have a `used_ids = set()` and keep track of used values.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = dict()
>>> x[(1,2,3,4)] = 1
>>> x
{(1, 2, 3, 4): 1}
```

It works just fine...

Note that a dictionary does not guarantee an order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dictionary `{(1,2,3,4):1, (2,3,4,5):2, ....., (n,n+1,n+2,n+3):n}`:

```
>>> N = 4
>>> {(i,i+1,i+2,i+3):i for i in range(1, N+1)}
{(2, 3, 4, 5): 2, (1, 2, 3, 4): 1, (4, 5, 6, 7): 4, (3, 4, 5, 6): 3}
```